# Eclipse group multi project gradle as one project

Tags: eclipse, gradle, multi-project

So I imported a gradle project using File->Import->Gradle->Existing gradle project. But that project is a multi project gradle. So it automatically created a lot of eclipse projects and now in my package explorer there are a lot of projects.
Is there a way to group all these projects into one in a way that inside the root project are all of the nested projects?

Comment: Use the _Project Explorer_ instead of the _Package Explorer_ and in the view menu (the three dots) choose _Projects Presentation > Hierarchical_ to show the projects nested instead of one below the other.

Comment: Thanks this works. But is there a way to do something like this in the package explorer as well?